# Netbeans Commented Test Cases Still Running

Tags: java, debugging, netbeans, junit, comments

I am working on debugging jUnit tests in NetBeans. I didn't write the code or the tests so I'm having to do a lot of debugging/stepping through. I have tried to comment out all tests except the one that is giving me the most amount of trouble. I have commented them out with a block comment and they all appear gray. When I run the file, however, all the tests are still running as before. I have tried to clean and build the project but nothing has changed. What do I do to properly comment out the test cases that I don't want to run in NetBeans?

Comment: Are you sure your testing the correct project?

Comment: Can you comment out just `@Test` on your every test method?

Comment: I've tried to just comment out the @Test method. Also, this works with every other testing class (100+) in the project.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Debug particular test alone]
Some times Test depends on @BeforeClass and @Before , so
Please do these steps

1. Select the particular test method as shown in figure.
2. Right click and choose "**Run Focused Test Method**" or "**Debug Focused Test method**"

Comment: I'm running an older version of netbeans (6.8) and don't have that feature. I can't update since I have to use what my company has given me.

Comment: @Nicole_Maguire Please upgrade you will get full benefit if you are running test alone then setup the test porject module in your latest netbeans